# Events provide Encapsulation to Delegates. Why to encapsulate?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have read that events provide encapsulation to delegates. What happens internally when we add method reference in delegates and when we add reference for a method in an event?

I can see code work same for these 2 cases. Why do we need to encapsulate delegates? My code can work only with delegates. For the 2 cases i have shared below my code is working same.

Case 1:

```
public delegate void PerformedCalculationEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);

public PerformedCalculationEventHandler PerformedCalculation = null;
```

Case 2:

```
public delegate void PerformedCalculationEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);

public event PerformedCalculationEventHandler PerformedCalculation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Events indeed wrap the Delegate into a pair of add (+=) and remove (-=). Now primarily that means that the class code and **only the class code** can raise or clean up the collection of registered delegates.

Without that, everyones code could do god knows what with them, completely ruining any reliability. And reliabiltiy is something Events can not live without.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please share one example or use case that can help me to understand this little bit more?

Comment: @VarunSetia Similar to Public and Private, it is really hard to showcase this. And similar to private, it is really about nobody else doing stuff they are not supposed to do with your code. The only other model for even registering events I know off is Implementing Interfaces. But C# and .NET got Delegates, so they did not have to settle for something that low.